# custom Sorting order - configuration in mongoDB

Tags: sorting, mongodb, configuration

I would like to know how to configure the DB for custom sorting sequence

Today, MongoDB sorts the String data in the following order: (used pattern to sort list of strings is ->    [Symbols][0-9][A-Z][a-z] )

Example: Present Sorted Order will be like this.

1. &%name
2. 123AppName
3. AppName
4. SentinnelName
5. **appsname**
6. **sampleName**

But the way we want this sort is different. Pattern can be->   [Symbols][0-9][Aa-Zz]

Example: Expected Sorted Order should be like this

1. &%name
2. 123AppName
3. AppName
4. **appsname**
5. SentinnelName
6. **sampleName**

And my question is, do you have any idea of how to configure in  mongoDB to customize regular expression pattern, to sort in our expected order. ?

I hope it is clear, if something is not clear please let me know to explain more in detail.

PS: I want to make this change at DB level, so that it holds the same for any strings when i do a sort over it.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, MongoDB does not implement collation yet. Implementing the [Unicode collation standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) is the *best* way for solving that, but as you can see while just glancing over that document, it's not going to be a simple task. Also, it would make sorting slower, and indexes larger. So for now, it's best to sort in your application, or add a field with your suggested sorting values—if you're crazy enough, you can implement the sorting algorithm from TR10 yourself.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't use a regex to sort strings. It sorts them in lexicographical order. It just so happens that "%" < "0", "0" < "A" and  "A" < "a" (based on their character codes).

However, "@" is lexicographically* between digits and capital letters. And it is sorted just like that.

```
% mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.0
connecting to: test
> db.sort.insert({s: '777'})
> db.sort.insert({s: 'AAA'})
> db.sort.insert({s: '@@@'})

> db.sort.find().sort({s: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa33a07758e53f27a9896a"), "s" : "777" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa33b67758e53f27a9896c"), "s" : "@@@" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa33ad7758e53f27a9896b"), "s" : "AAA" }
```

So, from the top of my head, I don't know a way to alter MongoDB's behaviour. You should sort in application instead.

* *Assuming ASCII or UTF-8 encoding*

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a key which by default sorts in the order you want. e.g.

```
> db.foo.insert({name: "&%name"})
> db.foo.insert({name: "123AppName"})
> db.foo.insert({name: "AppName"})
> db.foo.insert({name: "appsname"})
> db.foo.insert({name: "SentinnelName"})
> db.foo.insert({name: "sampleName"})

> db.foo.find().forEach(function(row) { db.foo.update({_id: row._id}, {$set: {sname: row.name.toLowerCase()}}); });

> db.foo.find()> db.foo.find({}, {name: 1}).sort({sname: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa32e2a1454519983b116e"), "name" : "&%name" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa32e8a1454519983b116f"), "name" : "123AppName" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa330ba1454519983b1170"), "name" : "AppName" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa3310a1454519983b1171"), "name" : "appsname" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa331aa1454519983b1173"), "name" : "sampleName" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4faa3315a1454519983b1172"), "name" : "SentinnelName" }
```